# Elasticsearch query in java for regex not working correctly- is the syntax wrong?

Tags: java, regex, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

Have not had luck finding answers but here is my situation:

`QueryBuilders.regexpQuery("regexExpression","\\-?*[0-9]3475[0-9]6")`;

> `QueryBuilders.simpleQueryStringQuery("\\-?*2347566);`

Both queries I ran and simplequery returns 2347566 with or without the "-" but the regex query doesn't return anything. The value I printed out for regex query is \-?*[0-9]3475[0-9]6 which is correct.
Does anyone know why this is happening? I set the flag to "all" as well.

To clarify, I have a database of phone numbers that could have +,# as prefix and the user can input those characters, * and numbers in the search field. The search should ignore all instances of +,# in the search so that if I have +123 in the database, 123 search will return that result or +123 should also return same result since I am treating the + as wildcard so 0 or 1 occurence.

For example, a +123*45* should return 123[0-9]45[0-9] with or without the + (or the other occurrence.)

I have tried searching using regex with purely * like 234**789 when I know there are many phone numbers that can be found if I use exact match like 23456789 or 23477789. But when I use the regex search only on * or [0-9], it returns nothing even though the value of the regex search is 234[0-9][0-9]789.

Comment: In regex, a quantifier (`?`) cannot be followed by another quantifier (`*`). Also, there's no need to escape `-` if it's not inside a character class.

Comment: Ok. What about other special chars like +? I tried with and without + and still didn't get the results. Am I missing something else?

Comment: (Disclaimer: I don't know Elasticsearch.) `+` means 1 or more, a succeeding `?` makes `+` only match as needed. `?` itself means 0 or 1. Please add more details on what you have and what you want to match.

Comment: It's not clear if you know that the regex is the one you want and elastic search is not working as you expected or something else. Have you tested the regex manually, in a set of different unit test? Please edit your post providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Show what data you have in elastic search, how you are trying to consume, what are the expected behavior and what is the actual behavior.

Comment: I have tested very basic search for example 123*567 in my search which regex value shows 123[0-9]567 and I get no results. I tried 1234567 as input and I got 1 hit.

Comment: Are you sure your problem has anything to do with elastic search, and it's not solely a regex problem? Your regex shows that your regex knowledge is not high. Have you tested your regex with your input using an online regex testing tool to verify it actually works? If not, consider rephrasing your question to be regex only and remove all traces of elastic search.

Comment: I used the simplest case of [0-9]123 when I know and tested 2123 exist but [0-9]123 it does not. I tested on online tool as well. What would you say is the syntax for the simplest regex case? Ex:input ="*234**8"; input.replace("*","[0-9]); the query I get is "[0-9]234[0-9][0-9]8".

Comment: Yeah so the issue was I was searching in a specific field and was not on the fields I want... so it was syntax on it..

Answer (score 0):

In the end I was using the wrong field for the query which i thought was there. Had to search across all fields to get some results.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has a great documentation on the regular expression syntax.
*[Wikipedia – Regular expression – Syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Syntax)*.

There are a few errors with your pattern.

Firstly, you'll only have to escape a hyphen character if it is within a *character class*, and is subsequently not the first, or only character, or appears after the final range.

So, it's attempting to match a value that begins with a *\* character.

> *"... I have tried searching using regex with purely * like 234**789 ..."*

The * character, in regular expression syntax, is a quantifier, as opposed to most Unix syntax that recognizes that as a wildcard character.

The meta-character you're looking for is the dot character, ..

Try the following pattern, and see if the results improve.

```
-?.[0-9]3475[0-9]6
```

Additionally, you can, optionally, use the *\d* syntax to represent a *[0-9]*.

```
-?.\d3475\d6
```

As a final note, you mention

> *"... phone numbers that could have +,# as prefix ..."*

Would that not mean the pattern should be

```
[+#]?\d3475\d6
```